# Types Error On ( RUN npm run build ) in dockerfile build

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I am trying to dockerize a node application which uses typescript.

This my `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM node:14 as builder
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g npm@8.4.0
RUN npm i
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g npm@8.4.0
RUN npm install --production

COPY --from=builder /usr/app/dist ./dist

COPY ./src/ormconfig.docker.ts ./src/ormconfig.ts
COPY .env .

EXPOSE 5000
CMD node dist/src/index.js
```

And this `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/data/postgres
    env_file:
      - docker.env
    networks:
      - postgres

  web:
    image: 619525/techwondoe:1
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/app/
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

The Error I am getting is :

```
=> ERROR [builder 7/7] RUN npm run build                                                                                                                                             16.3s
------
 > [builder 7/7] RUN npm run build:
#13 0.991
#13 0.991 > techwondoe-assignment@1.0.0 build
#13 0.991 > tsc -b
#13 0.991
#13 16.23 src/interfaces/controller.interface.ts(1,24): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/usr/app/node_modules/express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
#13 16.23   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
#13 16.23 src/middleware/error.middleware.ts(1,49): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/usr/app/node_modules/express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
#13 16.23   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
#13 16.23 src/app.ts(1,29): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'body-parser'. '/usr/app/node_modules/body-parser/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
#13 16.23   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/body-parser` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'body-parser';`
#13 16.23 src/app.ts(2,31): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'cookie-parser'. '/usr/app/node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
#13 16.23   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cookie-parser` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'cookie-parser';`
#13 16.23 src/app.ts(3,26): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/usr/app/node_modules/express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
#13 16.23   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
#13 16.23 node_modules/class-validator/types/decorator/string/IsAlpha.d.ts(2,25): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'validator'. '/usr/app/node_modules/validator/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
#13 16.23   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/validator` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'validator';`
#13 16.23 node_modules/class-validator/types/decorator/string/IsAlphanumeric.d.ts(2,25): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'validator'. '/usr/app/node_modules/validator/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
#13 16.23   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/validator` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'validator';`
#13 16.23 node_modules/class-validator/types/decorator/string/IsDecimal.d.ts(2,25): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'validator'. '/usr/app/node_modules/validator/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

and lot more errors like this only...

When I try to build locally i.e(`npm run build`) it builds perfectly, and gives no errors.
But on doing `docker build` it gives error.

Here are the dependencies of the application,

```js
{
  "name": "techwondoe-assignment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/server.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^14.3.2",
    "envalid": "^7.2.2",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.41"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8",
    "@types/pg": "^8.6.4",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.1",
    "node-gyp": "^8.4.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.11.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node -r ./src/server.ts ",
    "build": "tsc -b",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "typeorm:cli": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -f ./src/ormconfig.ts"
  },
  "author": "xyz",
  "license": "MIT",
}
```

The command I am trying is `docker build -t assignment:1 .`
Am I missing something ?

local `node --version : v14.17.0`
local `npm --version : 8.4.0`

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the actual error, rather than a screen shot?  At least for me the tiny text and dark-blue-on-black is hard to read, and I can't copy the text of the error to search for it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `--production` option for installing packages therefore type declarations are skipped. Remove it and it should work.

As mentioned, also need to remove NODE_ENV=production

Comment: I did tried that.. but getting the same error.
and the error occurs at `npm run build` stage

Comment: `ENV NODE_ENV=production` in the first stage has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

you may use the --force flag which might removes the error as sometimes due to security concerns, these errors pop up
RUN npm install --production --force

note: this may disable some of the security features. Do checkout before applying it